# How can I print the value, of the value, of a python variable

Tags: python, string, variables

I have a variable, that we'll call `x` , which stores the string `test`
I have another variable, that we'll call `y` , which stores the **string** value `x`

Is there any way that I could `print(y)` , in order to return `test`

In other words, how can I `print` the value of `y` which itself stores the **name** of the variable `x` ?

I should also mention that I cannot just `print(x)` , because x changes, (as does its string value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> x="test"      
>>> y="x"         
>>> eval(y)       
'test'
```

But [don't use eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice). A better approach would be to use a mapping, such as a dictionary.

```
>>> mapping = {"x": "test"}     
>>> mapping[y]                  
'test'
```

Actually, variables in python are in a dictionary anyway, accessible via either the [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) or [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) builtins. So, another way to access a name dynamically is…

```
>>> globals()[y]   
'test'
```

…but this is just a more magical and less clear solution to creating the dictionary that you really need.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary:

```
d = {"x": "test"}
y = "x"
print(d[y])
```

If you want to use variable `x` then you can set some value to `x` as initializing. As you said `x` value can change:

```
x = None # can be any value depending on the user. 
d = {x: "test"}
y = x
print(d[y])
```

Output:

```
"test"
```